# Enableing pritty printers using MinGW

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw, mingw-w64

So I have been through a lot on my attempt to enable pretty printing in gdb. I have MinGW-64 installed and also the gdb-python module. And all of that works.
But when I use the following gdb file as a source when using gdb I get the following error.

File:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/MinGW/share/gcc-9.2.0/python/libstdcxx/v6')
from printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:/MinGW/share/gcc-9.2.0/python/libstdcxx/v6\printers.py", line 1747, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    register_type_printers(obj)
  File "C:/MinGW/share/gcc-9.2.0/python/libstdcxx/v6\printers.py", line 1644, in register_type_printers
    add_one_type_printer(obj, 'basic_string', ch + 'string')
  File "C:/MinGW/share/gcc-9.2.0/python/libstdcxx/v6\printers.py", line 1630, in add_one_type_printer
    gdb.types.register_type_printer(obj, printer)
  File "c:\mingw\share\gdb/python\gdb\types.py", line 177, in register_type_printer
    locus.type_printers.insert(0, printer)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'type_printers'
c:\MinGW\bin\pp.gdb:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

When I searched for solutions I came across one thread that said the printers.py file expects a more modern version of gdb then the installed one. But I don't if that's true and I also can't find any other version of that print file. I could write all the pretty printers myself but that would be a massive waste of time since somebody else must have already done that.

Comment: This works for me with gdb 8.3. Do you have an older gdb? If yes, why don't you update to a newer one?

Comment: Ok, I have an older version (7.5) running but it doesn't seem like I can update that using MinGW 64. Does that mean I need to use a different way of installing gdb on windows?

Comment: You didn't say where you got this old gdb. MSYS2 certainly has a newer one.

Comment: Well, first of all, I really need to thank you for your support. And the way I got the gdb version was by installing mingw64 and then added gdb python in the MinGW-get GUI. I didn't use MSYS, I have a folder named that way in C:/mingw but that's it.

Comment: If you don't want to use MSYS2, you could also try [my personal gdb build](https://github.com/ssbssa/gdb/releases).